# android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file line #18:Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cab.app.book/com.epbit.ccv3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android

support.design.widget.NavigationView.

Added design and appcompat library and Tried in all the ways, but unable to solve the issue.

Please help

Comment: don't you think that adding your code helps more then just posting your error?

Answer (score -3):

Your layout's file has an error in line 18.